# Best way to show that a screenshot continues on the next page?

Tags: icons, presentation

I'm working on a presentation and need to show that a screenshot continues onto the next page. For some reason I'm having trouble finding the icon that is normally used - I feel like it's sort of a lightning bolt that indicates the page has been separated. Does anyone have a good example?

Comment: What is the medium? A multi-paged PDF? Something else? How about an arrow or the word "next"?

Comment: It's a multi page PDF - more or arrow would definitely work, but I was asked specifically for the lightning bolt sort of thing, which I've definitely seen but can't think of a way to search for it in google images or noun project.

Comment: How about going to icon sites and looking for lighting bolts? As for example: http://www.flaticon.com/search/lightning-bolt

Answer (score 4):

You can use a 'torn page' edging style to indicate that something is continued somewhere else and in a particular direction.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add black inset gradient inside image - it will suggest that image isn't displayed full.

EDIT - Example image
[image: screenshot]

I know that this gradient is too visible, I just wanted to show what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Add a sample to make your answer a bit clearer :)

Comment: Ok, sorry. Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way instructional designers use to show that the screenshot on a page is not complete is to show it by dashed-lines. As shown in figure 01

The same idea can be used to indicate that the screenshot is incomplete and next page shows the screenshot beginning with the dashed lines indicating continuation.

Another way is to use what we traditionally use while making flowcharts. Use the circle with  the number or alphabet and use same in the next page. I have tried to display in figure 02

[image]